# how to send string from one activity to another without starting second activity

Tags: android, string, android-activity

I want to pass string from one activity and compare that string value in 3rd 4th activity so I want to know how to pass value from one activity to another without starting that activity. I know intent way by using `startActivity(intent)` I don't want to start activity. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2098936/1992254

Comment: if you do not want to start activity how your values will be initialized

Comment: You need to explain more why you dont want to start activity immediately. Do you want to start it later? what is your use case? Please explain more in detail.

Comment: i want to start it later but not from that activity from which i want string values

Comment: Then save it in **SharedPreference** and Use it later .( when you start it later)

Comment: Please explain more. from which activity you want to pass the string/values and where are you planning to use them?

Comment: Instead of posting this type of questions.please read some android ebooks. so that you can understand basics

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can use in this case:

- Shared Preferences
- static variables (not recommended)

Comment: content provider, database, cloud,file

Comment: All that for just to store a simple string. NOPE. A lot of overhead don't you think? Cloud? really? what if internet is not available?

Comment: Shared Preferences is the best option in this scenario.